# What do you call torture which leaves no visible marks?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, physical torture that is painful, but, leaves no visible marks to provide any proof.

Comment: It is still torture, skillfully (proficiency gained through deplorable practice) done.

Comment: It's torture that doesn't leave any marks.

Comment: marriage (filler)

Comment: @V0ight - Ta-da-boom!

Comment: Sounds like waterboarding.

Comment: @Stan Of-course it is torture,but, I surely remember having heard specific term for it. I am unable to retrieve it.

Comment: @k1eran Waterboarding and Chinese water torture are specific forms, yes, but the practise has become a vast field in itself.

Comment: It's called "listening to politicians speak", though it often does leave marks due to banging your head against the wall.

Comment: I have heard the word "enhanced" used with describing American torture techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Some such practises may fit the legal definition of **"cruel and unusual punishment"**.

> **cruel and unusual punishment**  -
>   Punishment prohibited by the Eighth Amendment to the Constitution. 
>   Cruel and unusual punishment includes torture, deliberately degrading punishment, or punishment that is too severe for the crime committed [...] 
>   — 
>   [The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy, Third Edition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cruel-and-unusual-punishment)

Answer (score 0):

For a police interrogation context, you could call this "Third Degree":

from the [*Forensic Outreach*](http://forensicoutreach.com/library/4-police-interrogation-techniques-you-should-know-and-why-not-all-of-them-work/) website:

> Historically, confessions were a simple matter of applying the so-called third degree. Depriving the subject of food, water and sleep, applying physical discomfort, beating him with a rubber hose so as not to leave marks and even threats or intimidation eventually broke a subject or caused him to accept whatever story he was being fed — simply to stop the abuse. The intimidation would also continue a bit longer, however,  in order to get the subject to sign a paper saying he had not been coerced and his statement was voluntary. With the paper in hand and a blindfold over the statue of Lady Justice’s eyes, the admission would seal the suspect’s fate.

Comment: the third degree is a method of interrogation. it does not mean torture that leaves no marks.

Comment: To anyone on the receiving end, the semantic difference would be hard to appreciate.

Comment: "The third degree" may very well leave marks.